# Why is my code to swap two elements of a list going wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, swap, iterable-unpacking

Here is my code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a[0], a[a[0]] = a[a[0]], a[0]
print(a)
```

I'm trying to swap `a[0]` with `a[a[0]]` (i.e. `a[1]` in this case), so the result I expect is:

```
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

The result I get is `[2, 2, 1, 4, 5]`, which is not what I want.

if I simplify `a[0], a[a[0]] = a[a[0]], a[0]` to `a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]`, it works.

How can I make this swap inside a list work like `a, b = b, a` does?

Comment: `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a[0], a[a[0]] = a[a[0]], a[0];
print(a)`, in my system, it prints [2, 2, 1, 4, 5].

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake, [2, 2, 1, 4, 5] is true.

Comment: also mention, what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That assignment's doing quite a lot. Let's break everything down …

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Ok, that's the easy bit. Next:

```
a[0], a[a[0]] = a[a[0]], a[0]
```

The first thing that happens in any assignment is that the right hand side is evaluated, so:

`a[a[0]], a[0]` reduces to `a[1], a[0]`, which evaluates to `(2, 1)`.

Then, each assignment target in turn gets one of those items from the right hand side assigned to it:

```
a[0] = 2   # 2 == first item in the (already evaluated) right hand side
```

Now that's done, `a` looks like this:

```
[2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now we'll do the second assignment:

```
a[a[0]] = 1   # 1 == second item in the (already evaluated) right hand side
```

But wait! `a[0]` is now `2`, so this reduces to

```
a[2] = 1
```

And, lo and behold, if we look at `a` again, it's ended up as:

```
[2, 2, 1, 4, 5]
```

What you've discovered is that although Python claims to be able to swap two values simultaneously with e.g. `a, b = b, a`, that isn't really true. It almost always works in practice, but if one of the values is part of the description of the other one – in this case, `a[0]` is part of the description of `a[a[0]]` – the implementation details can trip you up.

The way to fix this is to store the initial value of `a[0]` before you start reassigning things:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
tmp = a[0]
a[0], a[tmp] = a[tmp], a[0]
```

After which, `a` looks the way you'd expect:

```
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: *"Python claims"* Where?

Answer (score 0):

python system lib `dis` module may help. The `dis` module supports the analysis of CPython bytecode by disassembling it. you can disassembling it to see how the swap works internally.

```
In [1]: import dis
In [2]: def func():
    ...:     a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    ...:     a[0], a[a[0]] = a[a[0]], a[0]
    ...:     print a

In [3]: func()
[2, 2, 1, 4, 5]

In [4]: dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
              9 LOAD_CONST               4 (4)
             12 LOAD_CONST               5 (5)
             15 BUILD_LIST               5
             18 STORE_FAST               0 (a)   # make list: a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  3          21 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)   # stack: a
             24 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)   # stack: a|a
             27 LOAD_CONST               6 (0)   # stack: a|a|0
             30 BINARY_SUBSCR                    # stack: a|1
             31 BINARY_SUBSCR                    # stack: 2
             32 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)   # stack: 2|a
             35 LOAD_CONST               6 (0)   # stack: 2|a|0
             38 BINARY_SUBSCR                    # stack: 2|1
             39 ROT_TWO                          # stack: 1|2
             40 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)   # stack: 1|2|a
             43 LOAD_CONST               6 (0)   # stack: 1|2|a|0
             46 STORE_SUBSCR                     # stack: 1|          a: a[0] = 2
             47 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)   # stack: 1|a
             50 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)   # stack: 1|a|a
             53 LOAD_CONST               6 (0)   # stack: 1|a|a|0
             56 BINARY_SUBSCR                    # stack: 1|a|2
             57 STORE_SUBSCR                     # stack:             a: a[2] = 1

  4          58 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             61 PRINT_ITEM
             62 PRINT_NEWLINE
             63 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             66 RETURN_VALUE
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html